# What does this really mean: Compiler Error Message: BC30451

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm getting this error in an open source project that runs fine on a dev machine with iis7, but breaks in iis6. Has anybody else gotten this message or is there a way to decifer it?

Comment: is this dotnetnuke that you are trying to run?

Answer (score 0):

I think that error message means you're using an object that doesn't exist.  My guess is the IIS7 machine has some dynamic link library registered that your II6 machine doesn't (or an outdated version).